# Dynamic content in pages

Tags: pages

I'm looking to have dynamic content in pages. I've created this page:

coaches/basketball/mike-johnson

That works great and does everything I want it to do.  However, I also want to create something like this without having to go into the admin and create a page each time:
coaches/basketball/joe-smith
coaches/basketball/ben-murray

Is there a good way to do this automatically without manually inserting a new page?  Would I need to create a PHP function that would add a page into the database?  That doesn't seem like it would scale well for thousands of coaches.

I understand how to create
coaches/basketball/page?coach_id=100
coaches/basketball/page?coach_id=101
coaches/basketball/page?coach_id=102
etc
This is what I'm really looking for, just with a clean URL and also so the page is searchable.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: automatically based on what? if you're not creating the content, where does it come from?

Comment: All of the data will come from the database. I'll have a table for all of the coaches information (name, contact info, etc.). I'm used to doing something like this without WordPress, but not within WordPress as you can probably tell.  If there's a better way to go about this let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If all that data is going in your database anyway, I suggest creating a coach [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) and sport [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies). additional data can be stored in [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).